# Django How to save an m2m field through a modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I save the values of payment_mode in my form to the PaymentChoices model?

**models.py**

```
  9 PAYMENT_MODE=(('Credit Card','Credit Card'),('Bank Transfer','Bank Transfer'),
 10               ('Bankdraft/Cheque','Bankdraft/Cheque'),
 11               ('Other','Other'))
 12 
 13 class PaymentChoices(models.Model):
 14     currency = models.CharField('Payment Modes', choices=PAYMENT_MODE, max_length=25)
 15 
 16 class EventPaymentDetail(models.Model):
 17     event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
 18     merchant_name = models.CharField('Merchant Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default='INMEET CMS PTE LTD')
 19     currency = models.CharField('Currency', choices=CURRENCY_LIST, default='SGD', max_length=3)
 20     payment_mode = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentChoices)
 21     transaction_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
 22     tax = models.DecimalField('Tax', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
 23     terms = models.CharField('Terms and Conditions', max_length=2500, blank=True, null=True)
 24     modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
 25     created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False)�editable=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
 9 class EventPaymentDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
 10     account_name = forms.CharField(label='Account Name', max_length=100, required=False)
 11     bank_name = forms.CharField(label='Bank Name', max_length=100, required=False)
 12     branch_name = forms.CharField(label='Branch Name', max_length=100, required=False)
 13     address = forms.CharField(label='Bank Address' ,max_length=100, required=False)
 14     account_number = forms.CharField(label='Account Number', max_length=50, required=False)
 15     payment_mode = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Payment Mode', widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=PAYMENT_MODE)
 16 
 17     class Meta:
 18         model = EventPaymentDetail
 19         fields = ('merchant_name',
 20                   'currency',
 21                   'payment_mode',
 22                   'account_name',
 23                   'account_number',
 24                   'bank_name',
 25                   'branch_name',
 26                   'address',
 27                   'transaction_prefix',
 28                   'tax',
 29                   'terms',)
 30         widgets = {'terms': forms.Textarea }
```

**views.py**

```
 20 @login_required
 21 @event_admin_only
 22 def payment_details(request, event_slug, role_id, module_slug):
 23     event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event_slug)
 24     payment_details = EventPaymentDetail.objects.get_or_create(event=event)[0]
 25     bank_details = EventBankAccountDetail.objects.get_or_create(event=event)[0]
 26 
 27     if request.method == 'POST':
 28         payment_form = EventPaymentDetailForm(request.POST, instance=payment_details)
 29         display_error(request, payment_form)
 30         if payment_form.is_valid():
 31 
 32             cd = payment_form.cleaned_data
 33             bank_details.account_number = cd['account_number']
 34             bank_details.bank_name = cd['bank_name']
 35             bank_details.address = cd['address']
 36             bank_details.account_name = cd['account_name']
 37             bank_details.branch_name = cd['branch_name']
 38             bank_details.save()
                # stuck here ???
 40             payment_details = payment_form.save()
 42 
 43             messages.success(request, 'Payment details successfully saved!')
 44             url = reverse('registration_item_details', args=[event_slug, role_id, module_slug])
 45             return redirect(url)
 46 
 47     else:
 48         initial_values={'account_number': bank_details.account_number,
 49                         'account_name': bank_details.account_name,
 50                         'bank_name': bank_details.bank_name,
 51                         'address': bank_details.address,
 52                         'branch_name': bank_details.branch_name}
 53         payment_form = EventPaymentDetailForm(initial=initial_values, instance=payment_details)
 54 
 55     template = 'registration/payment_details.html'
 56     return render(request, template, locals())
```

request.POST

```
{'bank_name': u'', 'terms': u'tesfefsef', 'branch_name': u'', 'tax': Decimal('0.10'), 'transaction_prefix': u'234', 'currency': u'SGD', 'account_number': '', 'address': u'', 'payment_mode': [u'Credit Card', u'Bank Transfer', u'Bankdraft/Cheque', u'Other'], 'account_name': u'', 'merchant_name': u'INMEET CMS PTE LTD'}
```

Comment: I think there's a special method for this form.save_m2m() which should be called after your form was saved (so it has an id)

Comment: @ArgsKwargs This is an anser, it really belongs in the answer field below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` like so:

```
payment_mode = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Payment Mode', widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=PaymentChoices.objects.all())
```

The initial values in the models will be empty so you will have to populate it with the values from the choice list.